# Activity Closing After Multiple Clicks

Tags: android, android-layout, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, android-view

Every time I run my app and I keep going to the next activity after clicking 15-16 times the next activity its says it is going to unfortunately close.

```
I/art: Alloc sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 907(64KB) AllocSpace objects, 1(16KB) LOS objects, 0% free, 95MB/96MB, paused 701us total 8.300ms
I/art: Clamp target GC heap from 99MB to 96MB
I/art: Alloc partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 248(18KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0% free, 95MB/96MB, paused 762us total 24.932ms
I/art: Clamp target GC heap from 99MB to 96MB
I/art: Alloc concurrent mark sweep GC freed 65(14KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0% free, 95MB/96MB, paused 732us total 39.672ms
I/art: Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 4MB allocation
I/art: Clamp target GC heap from 99MB to 96MB
I/art: Alloc concurrent mark sweep GC freed 11(344B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0% free, 95MB/96MB, paused 732us total 37.811ms
**E/art: Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 4665612 byte allocation with 638544 free bytes and 623KB until OOM"**
I/art: Alloc sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 5(576B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0% free, 95MB/96MB, paused 671us total 5.065ms
I/art: Clamp target GC heap from 99MB to 96MB
I/art: Alloc partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 6(192B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0% free, 95MB/96MB, paused 732us total 23.437ms
I/art: Clamp target GC heap from 99MB to 96MB
I/art: Alloc concurrent mark sweep GC freed 3(96B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0% free, 95MB/96MB, paused 915us total 43.914ms
I/art: Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 4MB allocation
I/art: Clamp target GC heap from 99MB to 96MB
I/art: Alloc concurrent mark sweep GC freed 3(96B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0% free, 95MB/96MB, paused 701us total 37.811ms
**E/art: Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 4665612 byte allocation** with 638544 free bytes and 623KB until OOM"
D/skia: --- allocation failed for scaled bitmap
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
**E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.example.microsoft.drawit, PID: 840
                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.microsoft.drawit/com.example.microsoft.drawit.letterO}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3133)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3243)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:218)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1718)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6917)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
                   Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:640)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:750)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:483)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:415)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:366)
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287)
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
                      at com.example.microsoft.drawit.letterO.onCreate(letterO.java:17)
                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6609)
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1134)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3086)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3243) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:218) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1718) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6917) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199) 
                   Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                      at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:614)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:750) 
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:483) 
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:415) 
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:366) 
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287) 
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139) 
                      at com.example.microsoft.drawit.letterO.onCreate(letterO.java:17) 
                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6609) 
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1134) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3086) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3243) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:218) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1718) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6917) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199) 
                   Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 4665612 byte allocation with 638544 free bytes and 623KB until OOM
                      at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
                      at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
                      at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:837)
                      at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:656)
                      at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:1037)
                      at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:4037)
                      at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:3910)
                      at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:776)
                      at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:4001)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:513)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:509)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:505)
                      at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.<init>(ConstraintLayout.java:419)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288) 
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:614) 
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:750) 
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:483) 
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:415) 
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:366) 
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287) 
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139) 
                      at com.example.microsoft.drawit.letterO.onCreate(letterO.java:17) 
                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6609) 
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1134) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3086) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3243) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:218) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1718) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6917) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)** 
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 840 SIG: 9
```

Comment: As the logs say, there is an `OutOfMemory` exception happening. What that means is that you leaking memory somewhere in your app which collects to the point where the OS doesn't have enough memory left to run your application.

Comment: This is most likely due to bitmap loading. Have a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477572/strange-out-of-memory-issue-while-loading-an-image-to-a-bitmap-object) and accepted answer for help

Comment: You may have a memory leak in `com.example.microsoft.drawit.letterO` class.  Can you share the class contents?